# ¿Por qué mi función para evaluar comandos no devuelve el resultado correcto?

Tags: javascript

Tengo problemas con el siguiente ejercicio. Cuando ejecuto el código mas abajo,
e ingreso `ppp`, el resultado deberia mostrarse como `*25**25**25*` pero me
aparece `***25***`. Y al utilizar el ejemplo me muestra `*NaN*`.

Esta es la consigna del ejercicio:

> Implementar una función en JS que recibe un string que contiene una secuencia de comandos que se asume en minúsculas (que se detalla más adelante) 
>   y un número y retorna un string con el resultado de aplicar dichos comandos en forma sucesiva a ese número.
>   Cada comando es un carácter y puede ser:
>   i: incrementar el número en 1
>   d: decrementar el número en 1
>   c: elevar al cuadrado el número
>   p: agregar el número al string resultado, entre “*”
>   Si viene cualquier otro carácter debe ser ignorado.
>   Ejemplo 1) se invoca a la función con la secuencia "iicxdpcp" y el valor 1, retorna: "*8**64*"

Y este es el código que hice:

```
var secuencia = prompt("Ingrese secuencia")
var numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese numero"))

function proceso(secuencia, numero) {
    for (i = 0; i <= secuencia.length; i++) {

        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "i") {
            numero++
        }

        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "d") {
            numero--
        }
        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "c") {

            numero = Math.pow(numero, 2)

        }

        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "p") {

            numero = "*" + numero + "*"

        }

    }
    return numero


    console.log(numero)

}



proceso(secuencia, numero)
```

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí bien tu consulta el tema va por esta linea

```
`numero = "*" + numero + "*"`
```

Cuando se tiene la secuencia `ppp` y el numero `25` debería ser así:

```
//Se encadena un texto en cada iteracción
var seq = "" 
var num = 25 (numero)

seq = seq      + "*"+ num + "*" (sentencia)    
seq = ""       +  * + 25  +  *  (primer loop)
seq = *25*     +  * + 25  +  *  (segundo loop)
seq = *25**25* +  * + 25  +  *  (tercer loop)
```

Se necesitan dos variables una del tipo `string` `seq` y otro del tipo `integer` `num` porque al tratar de tener una única variables `numero` esta se volverá `string` `"iicxdpcp"` en la primera `p` y cuando se llegue a la siguiente letra `c` arroja el código NaN ya que se está ejecutando

```js
console.log(Math.pow("*8*",2))   //NaN
```

El código quedaría en tal sentido así

```js
function proceso(secuencia, numero) {
    var num = numero
    var seq = ""
    
    for (i = 0; i <= secuencia.length; i++) {

        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "i") num++
        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "d") num--
        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "c") num = Math.pow(num, 2)

        if (secuencia.charAt(i) === "p") {
            
            seq = seq + "*" + num + "*" // `${seq}*${num}*`

        }

    }
    return seq
}


var secuencia = "ppp"
var numero = 25
ans = proceso(secuencia, numero)
console.log(ans)


var secuencia = "iicxdpcp"
var numero = 1
ans = proceso(secuencia, numero)
console.log(ans)
```